# VS Code Download Error

Tags: centos, download, dnf

I am using Centos and I get this error message on trying to download the vs
code for linux. I have tried updating the system but still no progress.Please help.

```
Total download size: 108 M
Installed size: 322 M
Downloading Packages:
[MIRROR] code-1.64.2-1644445844.el7.x86_64.rpm: Curl error (23): Failed writing received data to disk/application for https://packages.microsoft.com/yumrepos/vscode/code-1.64.2-1644445844.el7.x86_64.rpm [Failed writing body (381 != 16384)]
[FAILED] code-1.64.2-1644445844.el7.x86_64.rpm: Curl error (23): Failed writing received data to disk/application for https://packages.microsoft.com/yumrepos/vscode/code-1.64.2-1644445844.el7.x86_64.rpm [Failed writing body (381 != 16384)]

The downloaded packages were saved in cache until the next successful transaction.
You can remove cached packages by executing 'dnf clean packages'.
Error: Error downloading packages:
  Curl error (23): Failed writing received data to disk/application for https://packages.microsoft.com/yumrepos/vscode/code-1.64.2-1644445844.el7.x86_64.rpm [Failed writing body (381 != 16384)]
```

.

Comment: Failed to write? How about either disk errors or you have no free space left.

Comment: No space left on device: '/var/lib/dnf/rpmdb_lock.pid'  . I got this error. What shall i do

Comment: Get a bigger disk? Delete no longer required files? Clean out the log directory? Run `'dnf clean packages'` as it suggests? Wave a magic wand over it?